# How to manage Session in blobstoreService.createUploadUrl

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jsp, session

I have created a application in Google App Engine.....The app takes xml file as input and some xpaths.every after hitting the submit button a report is generated.If i return to the home page using browser back button the session is getting destroyed.Is there any way to keep the session active??

Code of the home page:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<%@ page import="com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.BlobstoreService.*" %>

<%@ page import="com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.BlobstoreServiceFactory" %>
<%@ page import="com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.BlobstoreService" %>

<%
    BlobstoreService blobstoreService = BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService();
%>
<html>
      <head>
          <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate">
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0">
          <script language="javascript">
function Checkfiles()
{
var fup = document.getElementById('myFile');
var fileName = fup.value;
var ext = fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
if(ext == "xml")
{
return true;
}
else
{
alert("Upload an XML File");
fup.focus();
return false;
}
}
</script>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>XSD Checking Tool</title>

            <style rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
body {
  color: #000000;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  font-family: arial, verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14pt;
}

fieldset {
  font-size: 14px;
 width: 600px;
}

.formPrompt {
  text-align: right;
}
.footer, .push {
    background-color: #ffffff;
height: 4em;
  font-size: 8pt;

}

input {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #000000;
  border-width: 1px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

            </style>
    </head>
   <body  bgcolor="Silver">
       <center>
       <h2 style="background-color:skyblue; bottom:20">XPath Checking Tool</h2>
       </center>

            <form action="<%= blobstoreService.createUploadUrl("/FileUpload") %>" onsubmit="return Checkfiles();" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<center>
Browse The File to Check XPaths:
<input type="file" name="myFile" id="myFile">

<hr />


<div style="font-size:12pt; color: black">
    <fieldset>
<legend>Paste the xpaths Here</legend>

<table>
    <td>
        <TEXTAREA NAME="xpath" id="xpath" ROWS="20" cols="40"></TEXTAREA><br>
</td>

</table>

    </fieldset>
        </div>
         </center>
                <center>
                <p><input type=submit value="Submit"></p>
                </center>
         <hr />

</form>
<center>
<div class="footer">
            <p style="background-color:skyblue">Copyright (c) 2012 Developed by Soumitra Chatterjee,Arpish Chatterjee & Dwaipayan Mukherjee</p>
        </div>
    </center>
</body>


</html>
```

Comment: Did you enable sessions in your appengine-web.xml file ?

Comment: yup...<sessions-enabled>true</sessions-enabled>

Comment: rickz the url of my deployed app is http://xapthcheckbeta.appspot.com/

Comment: I see what you mean. A new session ID is being sent with each request.  Did you change log level to debug and see if exceptions are being thrown ?  Also, I would create a simple page that can test sessions. That might tell you if it is your xpath app that is the problem.

Comment: Actuly the fronpage is trying to use the same session ID every time......but its getting destroyed on single run ...